# remove_function method removing next priority action too while removing current priority

Tags: filters, core

I found a strange behaviour from the WP core related to remove_action,

```
add_action('my_custom_hook', 'mycustomfunc2',99); 
add_action('my_custom_hook', 'mycustomfunc3',100);


function mycustomfunc1(){
    echo 'mycustomfunc1 <br/>';
}

function mycustomfunc2() {
    echo 'mycustomfunc2  <br/>';
    remove_action('my_custom_hook', 'mycustomfunc2',99);
}

function mycustomfunc3() {
    echo 'mycustomfunc3 <br/>';
}


add_action('wp', function(){

    do_action('my_custom_hook');
    exit;
});
```

here when we are removing mycustomfunc2 and the mycustomfunc3 automatically getting removed generating output like this-
https://imgur.com/Y3aMVfF
Appreciate if this being checked, initially it seems to be a clear bug.
I can ensure I am using WP version 6.4.3 with no change in core files.

Comment: are you sure this is because `mycustomfunc3` was removed and not because there was a crash/fatal error before it could run? It's best practice to add all your actions in the same place, and extremely unusual to call `exit` on the `wp` action like that without some sort of redirect needing it, or to remove action inside that hook. What are you trying to achieve that requires this?

Comment: I created the snippet to simplify the debugging and to reproduce easily, while the actual issue arised in much complex use case. 
We can ignore exit, its just to prevent script from running next. 
Possibility of breakages seems to be none in snippet that small, the do_action will run all assigned actions and then jump to next line. 
Removing action hook inside the same action has a use case where we do not want a particular action to run multiple times when do_action calls again. We have other ways to solve it. But I am questioning the core behaviour here and seeking any insight on same.